# Paste excel link formula using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in an organization where we have 100s of excel files on our shared drive. These excel files contain asset numbers to our company assets in different cells within the files. What I would like to do is create a script in vba which would run only once and search through all these excel files using the find method and paste their cell addresses adjacent to their file path (I already have the paths of all the files in an excel sheet). But this address should in the form of a link formula, just like "=A2" so that we can later on modify this formula if there is a change in the position of the asset number without using vba. So suppose,

If cell E3 in the file1 contains asset number "XXX0000", the vba script should paste something like " ='\shared drive\folder path\file1.xlsx]WS'!$E$3 " in the cell next to the path,"\shared drive\folder\". So later on we can manually modify this formula if there is a change in its cell location

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to do? Can you show us any of the code you are having problem with?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: enderland, what is your problem? If u don't want to help please refrain from posting such nonsense